# Annoying navbar box on mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have [this annoying box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYLsg.png) on the dropdown menu option. But it is annoying on mobile view only and not on the desktop version. I looked up the bootstrap stylesheet and it has something to do in here `.dropdown-menu.show { display: block; }`

Any solution for this?

Comment: `Display: block` here doesn't exactly specify anything. It means that the item takes the whole row or block. This requires more context.

Comment: Do you use the latest version? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ cause I don't see this over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ".dropdown-menu.show { display: block; }" in your stylesheet and set a "z-index: 999;" property in it, which will make it go over any other object (including the box which is appearing on screen when the dropdown is activated).